# jqgrid - grouping whit spaces column

Tags: jqxgrid, jqxwidgets

I wonder if there is a way to leave the cluster plugin with JQGrid grid view like this:
http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-grouping.htm

I'm getting to group, but the column is not with the spacing above the level of the group and hide the column if there be grouped all the other comes to the corner.
Is there a way to leave with a vision of grouping, but with the same hierarchy example of a plugin that showed up?
hugs